# lodash's uniquby returing wrong result to me

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

enter code hereFollowing array am getting with the api response,

```
[{"imgPaths":["gallery/products/11dc67c40ea3812d5f5f8b8585a202f6"],"_id":"5f3e966a65c6d591ba04f3dd","productName":"SBL Arsenic Album 30 CH (30ml) ","categoryId":{"_id":"5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3","categoryName":"Homeopathy","imgPath":"gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd"},"manufacturer":"SBL ","basePrice":"85","finalPrice":"77","availability":"in-stock","createdAt":"2020-08-20T15:27:38.484Z"},{"imgPaths":["gallery/products/4d2235903695423f957abb831f6b7266"],"_id":"5f3e967265c6d591ba04f3de","productName":" Dr. Reckeweg Arsenic Album 30 CH (11ml)  ","categoryId":{"_id":"5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3","categoryName":"Homeopathy","imgPath":"gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd"},"manufacturer":"Dr. Reckeweg","basePrice":"115","finalPrice":"115","availability":"in-stock","createdAt":"2020-08-20T15:27:46.261Z"},{"imgPaths":["gallery/products/a8fd4422565c7f78fb8d5578e9da2143"],"_id":"5f3e967a65c6d591ba04f3df","productName":"SBL Camphora 1M (1000 CH) (30ml)  ","categoryId":{"_id":"5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3","categoryName":"Homeopathy","imgPath":"gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd"},"manufacturer":"SBL","basePrice":"120","finalPrice":"101","availability":"in-stock","createdAt":"2020-08-20T15:27:54.594Z"},{"imgPaths":["gallery/products/1ba84342e40856e71a64bf4b840fe611"],"_id":"5f3e968165c6d591ba04f3e0","productName":"Dr. Reckeweg R89 (Lipocol) (30ml)  ","categoryId":{"_id":"5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3","categoryName":"Homeopathy","imgPath":"gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd"},"manufacturer":"Dr. Reckeweg","basePrice":"270","finalPrice":"269","availability":"in-stock","createdAt":"2020-08-20T15:28:01.150Z"},{"imgPaths":["gallery/products/11542fe755e53ff08a983257dbaf12c3"],"_id":"5f3e968a65c6d591ba04f3e1","productName":"SBL Nux Vomica 30 CH (30ml)  ","categoryId":{"_id":"5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3","categoryName":"Homeopathy","imgPath":"gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd"},"manufacturer":"SBL","basePrice":"85","finalPrice":"80","availability":"in-stock","createdAt":"2020-08-20T15:28:10.468Z"},{"imgPaths":["gallery/products/7ff26dfa8c524e3cc289805819b25bac"],"_id":"5f3eb0eb8861ac98fd52fc8c","productName":"SBL Bryonia Alba 200 CH (30ml)","categoryId":{"_id":"5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3","categoryName":"Homeopathy","imgPath":"gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd"},"manufacturer":"SBL","basePrice":"95","finalPrice":"90","availability":"in-stock","createdAt":"2020-08-20T17:20:43.508Z"}]
```

i  am trying to get unique values from manufacturer with lodash array,

```
const _=require('lodash');
const uniqueArr =_.uniqBy(res.data,'manufacturer');
console.log(uniqueArr.map(item=>item.manufacturer));
```

and getting the result as below

```
["SBL ", "Dr. Reckeweg", "SBL"]
```

It is considering 1st and 3rd value as different due to the space,
so how can we remove the pre and post spaces from object values so that
this unique method will output as below

```
["Dr. Reckeweg", "SBL"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The value `'manufacturer'` is an iteratee shorthand for `_ => _.manufacturer`. You can change it to use the trimming function.

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const uniqueArr =_.uniqBy(res.data, item => item.manufacturer.trim());
console.log(uniqueArr.map(item => item.manufacturer.trim()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to `trim` that `manufacturer` first

```js
const res = _.chain(data)
  .map((obj) => ({ ...obj, manufacturer: obj.manufacturer.trim() }))
  .uniqBy("manufacturer")
  .map((obj) => obj.manufacturer)
  .value()
```

---

Full code

```js
const data = [
  {
    imgPaths: ["gallery/products/11dc67c40ea3812d5f5f8b8585a202f6"],
    _id: "5f3e966a65c6d591ba04f3dd",
    productName: "SBL Arsenic Album 30 CH (30ml) ",
    categoryId: {
      _id: "5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3",
      categoryName: "Homeopathy",
      imgPath: "gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd",
    },
    manufacturer: "SBL ",
    basePrice: "85",
    finalPrice: "77",
    availability: "in-stock",
    createdAt: "2020-08-20T15:27:38.484Z",
  },
  {
    imgPaths: ["gallery/products/4d2235903695423f957abb831f6b7266"],
    _id: "5f3e967265c6d591ba04f3de",
    productName: " Dr. Reckeweg Arsenic Album 30 CH (11ml)  ",
    categoryId: {
      _id: "5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3",
      categoryName: "Homeopathy",
      imgPath: "gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd",
    },
    manufacturer: "Dr. Reckeweg",
    basePrice: "115",
    finalPrice: "115",
    availability: "in-stock",
    createdAt: "2020-08-20T15:27:46.261Z",
  },
  {
    imgPaths: ["gallery/products/a8fd4422565c7f78fb8d5578e9da2143"],
    _id: "5f3e967a65c6d591ba04f3df",
    productName: "SBL Camphora 1M (1000 CH) (30ml)  ",
    categoryId: {
      _id: "5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3",
      categoryName: "Homeopathy",
      imgPath: "gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd",
    },
    manufacturer: "SBL",
    basePrice: "120",
    finalPrice: "101",
    availability: "in-stock",
    createdAt: "2020-08-20T15:27:54.594Z",
  },
  {
    imgPaths: ["gallery/products/1ba84342e40856e71a64bf4b840fe611"],
    _id: "5f3e968165c6d591ba04f3e0",
    productName: "Dr. Reckeweg R89 (Lipocol) (30ml)  ",
    categoryId: {
      _id: "5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3",
      categoryName: "Homeopathy",
      imgPath: "gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd",
    },
    manufacturer: "Dr. Reckeweg",
    basePrice: "270",
    finalPrice: "269",
    availability: "in-stock",
    createdAt: "2020-08-20T15:28:01.150Z",
  },
  {
    imgPaths: ["gallery/products/11542fe755e53ff08a983257dbaf12c3"],
    _id: "5f3e968a65c6d591ba04f3e1",
    productName: "SBL Nux Vomica 30 CH (30ml)  ",
    categoryId: {
      _id: "5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3",
      categoryName: "Homeopathy",
      imgPath: "gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd",
    },
    manufacturer: "SBL",
    basePrice: "85",
    finalPrice: "80",
    availability: "in-stock",
    createdAt: "2020-08-20T15:28:10.468Z",
  },
  {
    imgPaths: ["gallery/products/7ff26dfa8c524e3cc289805819b25bac"],
    _id: "5f3eb0eb8861ac98fd52fc8c",
    productName: "SBL Bryonia Alba 200 CH (30ml)",
    categoryId: {
      _id: "5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3",
      categoryName: "Homeopathy",
      imgPath: "gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd",
    },
    manufacturer: "SBL",
    basePrice: "95",
    finalPrice: "90",
    availability: "in-stock",
    createdAt: "2020-08-20T17:20:43.508Z",
  },
]

const res = _.chain(data)
  .map((obj) => ({ ...obj, manufacturer: obj.manufacturer.trim() }))
  .uniqBy("manufacturer")
  .map((obj) => obj.manufacturer)
  .value()

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `map` before `uniq`

**https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy**

```js
const data = [{"imgPaths":["gallery/products/11dc67c40ea3812d5f5f8b8585a202f6"],"_id":"5f3e966a65c6d591ba04f3dd","productName":"SBL Arsenic Album 30 CH (30ml) ","categoryId":{"_id":"5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3","categoryName":"Homeopathy","imgPath":"gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd"},"manufacturer":"SBL ","basePrice":"85","finalPrice":"77","availability":"in-stock","createdAt":"2020-08-20T15:27:38.484Z"},{"imgPaths":["gallery/products/4d2235903695423f957abb831f6b7266"],"_id":"5f3e967265c6d591ba04f3de","productName":" Dr. Reckeweg Arsenic Album 30 CH (11ml)  ","categoryId":{"_id":"5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3","categoryName":"Homeopathy","imgPath":"gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd"},"manufacturer":"Dr. Reckeweg","basePrice":"115","finalPrice":"115","availability":"in-stock","createdAt":"2020-08-20T15:27:46.261Z"},{"imgPaths":["gallery/products/a8fd4422565c7f78fb8d5578e9da2143"],"_id":"5f3e967a65c6d591ba04f3df","productName":"SBL Camphora 1M (1000 CH) (30ml)  ","categoryId":{"_id":"5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3","categoryName":"Homeopathy","imgPath":"gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd"},"manufacturer":"SBL","basePrice":"120","finalPrice":"101","availability":"in-stock","createdAt":"2020-08-20T15:27:54.594Z"},{"imgPaths":["gallery/products/1ba84342e40856e71a64bf4b840fe611"],"_id":"5f3e968165c6d591ba04f3e0","productName":"Dr. Reckeweg R89 (Lipocol) (30ml)  ","categoryId":{"_id":"5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3","categoryName":"Homeopathy","imgPath":"gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd"},"manufacturer":"Dr. Reckeweg","basePrice":"270","finalPrice":"269","availability":"in-stock","createdAt":"2020-08-20T15:28:01.150Z"},{"imgPaths":["gallery/products/11542fe755e53ff08a983257dbaf12c3"],"_id":"5f3e968a65c6d591ba04f3e1","productName":"SBL Nux Vomica 30 CH (30ml)  ","categoryId":{"_id":"5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3","categoryName":"Homeopathy","imgPath":"gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd"},"manufacturer":"SBL","basePrice":"85","finalPrice":"80","availability":"in-stock","createdAt":"2020-08-20T15:28:10.468Z"},{"imgPaths":["gallery/products/7ff26dfa8c524e3cc289805819b25bac"],"_id":"5f3eb0eb8861ac98fd52fc8c","productName":"SBL Bryonia Alba 200 CH (30ml)","categoryId":{"_id":"5f21376c2d46a455487b2ea3","categoryName":"Homeopathy","imgPath":"gallery/category/a7eafa3b8a480dd7d6810dee823104fd"},"manufacturer":"SBL","basePrice":"95","finalPrice":"90","availability":"in-stock","createdAt":"2020-08-20T17:20:43.508Z"}]

const uniqueArr = _.uniqBy(_.map(data, 'manufacturer'), _.trim);

console.log(uniqueArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```